# Convert date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that on page load looks like this:

```
<input type="input" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="May 12, 2012"/>
```

I want the following to happen:

- When a user clicks on the field to enter a date, the format changes to YYYY-MM-DD. (2012-05-12)
- After a user leaves the field, the format changes back to MMM DD, YYYY (May 12, 2012).
- When the data is submitted via post, it is in the format YYYY-MM-DD (2012-05-12).

How would I accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: Date manipulation is pure JavaScript, there's nothing in jQuery (of which I'm aware) to simplify this. Though [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'd suggest you get [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) and use all the conversions built into that library rather than writing it all from scratch.

Comment: Why all the conversion? My date fields get formatted on the server to be like your "May 12, 2012" when they're being sent to the form, but the server will accept dates entered in `MMM DD, YYYY` (3-letter abbreviated month) or `M* DD, YYYY` (spelled-out month) or `YYYY-MM-DD` or `MM/DD/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YY` (converting a 2-digit year via y2k style rules) etc. I just attempt parsing the submitted date in a bunch of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on specific frameworks/plugins, you can do this:

```
$("#start_date").click(function() {
    var d = new Date($(this).val());
    $(this).val(d.getFullYear() + "-"
        + String(d.getMonth() + 101).slice(-2) + "-"
        + String(d.getDate() + 100).slice(-2));
}).blur(function() {
    // Eventual format checking goes here

    var m = $(this).val().split("-"),
        d = new Date(m[0], m[1] - 1, m[2]),
        s = d.toString().split(" ");
    $(this).val(s[1] + " " + s[2] + ", " + s[3]);
});
```